# How to animate a customizable pixel art platformer character?

Tags: unity, animation, skeletal-animation, pixel-art

I am working on a 2d platformer which is made up of pixel art. I want to make my character customizable like in stardew valley. How can I implement it and create animations for my game like run , idle ,etc.

Comment: adding a child object to your players game object will make it follow the same transform position and rotation as its parent. These child objects can be activated with gameObject.SetActive(true/false); . The animations is another story, you can start by following the manual here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Sprites.html or I found this tutorial from Unity very helpful also https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-sprite-animations#5fa66921edbc2a0020bcaade